# Make manage file in different directory

Tags: makefile

I have a program to compile a Less file into a CSS file. I've made a wildcard make target, which calls `lessc` with appropriate arguments to create the CSS file in the same directory:

```
%.css: %.less node_modules/less/bin/lessc
    node_modules/less/bin/lessc $< $@
```

This produces the following output directory structure:

```
css/
|- foo.less
|- foo.css
```

This works perfectly. However, I'd like to adopt a different directory structure:

```
css/
|- foo.css
|- less/
   |- foo.less
```

However, I can't work out a sensible way to manage creation of a file in a different directory using make (I particularly want to avoid unnecessary recompilation). How can I change my target to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: `%.css: less/%.less ...`

Comment: What about if I want to compile foo/bar.css? It'll look for less/foo/bar.css, whereas it should look for foo/less/bar.css.

Comment: Are you sure about that? That's not how pattern rules match generally. That `%.css: less/%.less` should map `foo/bar.css` to `foo/less/bar.css` I believe. (And it seems to work in a quick test.) See [How Patterns Match](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) specifically the second paragraph (starts "When the target pattern").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to put the required prefix on the prerequisite. make handles the rest.

```
%.css: less/%.less node_modules/less/bin/lessc
        node_modules/less/bin/lessc $< $@
```